# Eclipse:Dynamic Web Application shows blank page when run on server

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I am following this guide specifically: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html

upon running the xthml file on the server I receive a blank page and I am not entirely sure as to why.

Hopefully there is an easy fix to this. I can supply more information if needed. Thanks!

Here is the xhtml file I am trying to run on server (apache tomcat6)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.name}"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="login"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

and here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Xperiment</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Probably some misconfiguration in your JSF project. Please post the web.xml and the content of the xhtml file you're trying to display in your browser.

Comment: added those files, they should also be viewable given the link I have in the description.

Comment: How are you accessing to the xhtml file, I mean, which URL are you using?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Xperiment/faces/login.xhtml is the url I am using wher Xperiment is the name of the project.

Comment: I cannot be sure why it is not displayed. The only thing I may say is to try removing the `<ui:component>` and the `<ui:define>` tags from your current xhtml file.

Comment: yay that worked actually thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<ui:define>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) should be used to define sections in a template file for other views, so the other views will use `<ui:insert>` to define the components for each specific view. Since your view will work as a template file to follow, there's no `content` section to display, so JSF will display nothing (blank page).

Removing `<ui:define>` tag should make your view work as expected.

More info:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4792862/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

If in this tutorial page [JSF Tools tutorial - Build a JSF 2.0 application](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html) is something wrong, first try to create simpler example first.

After customizing your web application for JSF, it means in Eclipse Properties-> Check Check box JavaServer Faces... etc to include JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.2) libray and creating `faces-config.xml` file as default, try this example inside: [JSF - template tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_templates_tag.htm). If it works, compare the example with your code. To enable-disable some parts of page1, page2 you can see, how clause `<ui:define>` works.